Does Shabbat starts at what for the rest of the world is 12 PM on Friday?
In Genesis 1:5 it reads:

God called the light Day and called the darkness Night. And there
was evening and there was morning, a first day

Does evening (the english translation of the word "erev" in hebrew) refer to noon?
How is called the period of time between 12 PM and 18 PM? morning?

By '12 pm' (which denotes 12 noon), do you perhaps mean '12 am' (which denotes midnight)?

I'm inquiring about 12 PM, also known as 12 noon. In my view, identifying 12 noon is simpler since it merely involves checking to see if the sun is directly above you.

@lifeisaquestion "tarde" can also mean noon? I don't speak spanish (but  יהושע ק might!)

noon in spanish is "mediodia" which in english can be translated as: middle day

When I mention 'checking to see if the sun is directly above you,' I'm referring to verifying if the sun is at the zenith.

@lifeisaquestion I don't follow your logic at all. You said in your comments that you feel you've made a mistake because of the spanish translation of erev = tarde. Where did noon come from? Does the verse say mediodia in spanish translations? If so, why would you think Shabbat starts at noon, from what it says?

In the Spanish translation, it does not say 'noon' (mediodía); it says 'tarde'. I believe Shabbat starts at noon because noon lasts until 12:59 PM, and then 'tarde' begins at 1 PM.

I believe it's preferable to set the cutoff point at noon because it stays consistent in both winter and summer.

@lifeisaquestion I think I know what's going on here. In most of Spain, specifically, they use the term 'tarde' to mean something akin to the English 'evening' (so they'll say something like 'Vamos a cenar a las 9 de la tarde'), whereas in Latin America and Judeo-Spanish the term 'tarde' refers to the period between 12 noon and when it gets dark.

Get yourself an Artscroll Spanish 'jumash' and you won't have these issues again: https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422615331.html

@יהושעק so glad to have you here! Jag Samayaj!

You have brought the actual proof that Shabbat starts when traditional Judaism holds that it starts: Friday evening (SA OC 261).
A day starts in the evening, followed by a morning (until the next evening).
Therefore the day of Shabbat starts Friday evening.

Sources: Berachot 2a, Shabbat 34a

sorry for such a stupid question, I have fallen into what is called lack of "text comprehension"

@lifeisaquestion the question of "when is evening" is not one that textual comprehension can help a lot with. Review the gemara in berachot

As a Spanish speaker, I've noticed a discrepancy in the translation of the word 'evening' in Genesis 1:5. In Spanish, 'evening' is translated as 'tarde,' which we typically understand to mean the time period starting at 12 PM and ending at sunset, marking the transition to night. However, this translation may present a challenge due to its limited scope within the spanish language.

@lifeisaquestion ah fair enough. Well, "erev" in hebrew means around sunset/first stars rather than midnight (but as I said, defining exactly when that is is a question for the gemara)

oh, now I remember, in spanish there is a word for erev/evening, and it is: vespertino. But in Genesis it reads "tarde" and not "vespertino" as, I think, it shoud be

Is there any word in hebrew for "afternoon"?
